# Selecting HTML drop-down through C#

Tags: c#, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select a HTML drop-down option through c# however Im not sure where to start. Could someone give a basic example.
Thanks in advance

Edited: This drop down I'm selecting is on someone's web page off the internet.

Edited: Below is the html on the webpage:
The drop down menu that contain "Ratings Data Upload" is what I am after to select.

```
<li class="dropdown ">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false"  aria-haspopup="true" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li class="">
      <a href="/ARAPS/Ratings/Upload">Ratings Data Upload</a>
</li>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are building an ASP.Net product? Are you trying to do this from the Code Behind? Or the Designer code?

Comment: At the end of the day, it is standard HTML. Add a `selected` attribute to the item you want to show selected.

Comment: It's not clear if the HTML is produced by your app (a View or Blazor) or you are manipulating a browser with an external c# tool.

Comment: Sorry the html is from an internet search.

Comment: Are you trying to use C# to select an option in a drop down from someone else's web page? Or are you writing your own web page?

Comment: @John Glenn Yes, I'm trying to select a drop-down choice from someone else's web page on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great browser automation framework called [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). Your next step should be using tutorials or online training content to learn Selenium (or another tool).

Selecting a drop down value with Selnium is as easy as:

```
Select objSelect =new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("search-box-id")));
objSelect.selectByVisibleText("Name of option shown to user");
```

Comment: I'm sure this will work, however as you see I attached the elements above. In the code there is not a "search-box-id". Is there maybe something else I could replace the id with?